# Overflow-y issues with 100% height

Tags: css, web-applications, height, overflow

I am creating a mobile friendly web app in which we display a popup with logged in user details.

I am trying to user overflow to create a more natural user interface, however the overflow-y property doesn't seem to be working as expected.

The div that I am trying to scroll is within a section that has a fixed position as its a modal type interface, there are also various other elements within this div.

Please take a look the the code below, I have provided the whole section beneath this excerpt so you can see the type of environment that its in.

```
<div class="notesDisplay">
  <div id="contain">
    <div id="sec-1">
      <div class="userHead">
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <img src="user/userDefault/icon.svg" alt="Your Icon" />
          <h4>Mark Brown</h4>
          <p>10 Connections</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="userOptions">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" title="sketch">Sketch</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="update">Update</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="settings">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="logout">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sec-2">
      <div class="userSelect">
        <ul>
          <li>Notifications</li>
          <li>Requests</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="userNotes">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="#" alt="Jbantock's Icon">
            <div>
              <h4><strong>Jbantock</strong> sent you a message.</h4>
              <p class="smallText">3 Hours Ago</p>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="2730 -1862 18 4">
              <g id="group-10" transform="translate(1650 -2375)">
                <circle id="ellipse-19" class="cls-1" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" transform="translate(1080 513)" />
                <circle id="ellipse-19-2" data-name="ellipse-19" class="cls-1" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" transform="translate(1087 513)" />
                <circle id="ellipse-19-3" data-name="ellipse-19" class="cls-1" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" transform="translate(1094 513)" />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </li>
          <!-- Three more of these -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="userRequests">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="#" alt="Jbantock's Icon">
            <div>
              <h4><strong>Jbantock</strong></h4>
              <p class="smallText">3 Hours Ago</p>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="2730 -1862 18 4">
              <g id="group-10" transform="translate(1650 -2375)">
                <circle id="ellipse-19" class="cls-1" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" transform="translate(1080 513)" />
                <circle id="ellipse-19-2" data-name="ellipse-19" class="cls-1" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" transform="translate(1087 513)" />
                <circle id="ellipse-19-3" data-name="ellipse-19" class="cls-1" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" transform="translate(1094 513)" />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </li>
          <!-- Three more of these -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the complete markup (sorry I know its long), the element I'm trying to scroll is .userRequests and the styles of that and its parent are:

```
li
  width: 442px
  text-align: center
  color: lighten($textGrey, 20%)
  height: 28px
  line-height: 28px
  border: 1px solid lighten($textGrey, 20%)
  box-sizing: border-box
  &:first-child
    border-radius: 5px
  &:last-child
    border-radius: 5px

li.selected
  background: lighten($textGrey, 20%)
  color: $noHoverWhite
  border: none

.userNotes, .userRequests
   display: inline-block
   overflow-y: scroll
   height: 100%
   width: 442px
```

Using sass by the way (don't hate appreciate)

Any ideas on what is causing this would be great, I've tried all of the suggestions I could find on here but none seem to get me where I want to be! :(

Comment: When using percent for height, all the chain of parents back to the body, or an element with a fixed height, is necessary for it to work. Do you have that?

Comment: Thank you, I just checked and I do (which is annoying), and to be sure I just double checked.... I think I'm going insane, any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the `100%` full viewport height? ... if so, try use viewport units instead, like `100vh`

Comment: And if your headers and stuff has a fixed height, say 80px summed up, try use that with calc, like this `height: calc(100vh - 80px)`

Comment: The highest parent to the body element is set to a height calculated by java (innerHeight - headerHeight = ###px), and the body element has no set height. Using viewport units makes some of the element in question hidden behind others. :(

Comment: What height does the class `.notesDisplay` have and what height does the id element `sec-2` have?

Comment: What also look weird is that both the `.userNotes` and the `.userRequests` have 100% height, being siblings that should not be possible

Comment: 'Sec-2' is set to 'height:100%' whilst '.notesDispaly' is 'height: calc(100vh - 100px)'

Comment: What about the height on `<div id="contain">` and `<div id="sec-1">`?

Comment: So I nested .notesDisplay and .userRequests inside another div and gave that a height of 100% (still no change) and the contain height is 100% and sec-1 is 350px

Comment: Is by any change the content inside the `.userNotes` and the `.userRequests` floated?

Comment: No I'm using flex-box for the majority of the layout... But.... I have just fiddled with some more height values and after solidifying some heights that aren't going to change it is now working! Thank you very much for your help, it is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Was going to ask about flexbox, it has some issues when it comes to define height and get scrollable content. One often need to set the scollable element to position absolute